# I want to fill rectangle on click event fill with rgb() random color

Tags: javascript, html

I already created Rectangle in html. and now the main part in which i face problem is:

i want to fill rectangle on click. Means, in rectangle if i click on middle of the rectangle then rectangle must be fill RGB color(random) from start to my click coordinator points.(left to right).

After this, i click on remaining part in any position, then it fill rgb color from last coordinate to my new click coordinate and also last RGB color(random) must be there as well.

Please help me for making this.

Here is my code :

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
                <title></title>
                <style type="text/css">
                    canvas {border: 1px solid black;}
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
            <canvas width="300" height="100" id="myCanvas" onclick="showCoords(event)"></canvas>
    
            <p id="demo"></p>
    
            <script>
            function showCoords(event) {
               var x = event.clientX;
              var y = event.clientY;
    
            var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            ctx.fillRect(x, y, 150, 100);
    
              //var coords = "X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y
              //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = coords;
            }
            </script>
    
    
    
            </body>
            </html>
```

```
      Thanks in Advance !!!
```

Comment: You are duplicating your question: [i want to create rectangle & on click event rectangle fill with rgb() color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58123018/i-want-to-create-rectangle-on-click-event-rectangle-fill-with-rgb-color)